# Вертикальное и горизонтальное выравнивание блоков

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Есть блоки, которые надо красиво расположить, я использовал flex, но у меня после перевода на новую строку остается место пустое, а надо чтобы там были элементы.
[image: Скрин]
Код: https://yadi.sk/d/smAzrtXy3KjwyZ

Comment: Ваша ссылка на проект тут не к чему, это не фриланс биржа. А вот Ваш код был бы очень кстати! Вообще похоже на masonry сетку https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Такое имхо проще флоатами сделать чем флексом

Answer (score 1):

Делается такое не с помощью flex, а с помощью float

```css
body {margin: 0;}

.parent {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px red, inset -2px 2px 0px red, inset 2px -2px 0px red, inset -2px -2px 0px red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  float: left;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px blue, inset -2px 2px 0px blue, inset 2px -2px 0px blue, inset -2px -2px 0px blue;
}

.child.big {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vw;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px green, inset -2px 2px 0px green, inset 2px -2px 0px green, inset -2px -2px 0px green;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child big"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```